# Get all first string in array object

Tags: lodash

I have the following array:

```
[
        {
            "name":"John Smith"
        },
        {
            "name":"Mary Kay"
        },
        {
            "name":"Peter Pan"
        },
        {
            "name":"Ben Franklin"
        }
    ];
```

How can I get all the first string name with lodash, like:

```
result = ["John", "Mary", "Peter", "Ben"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    console.log(_.map(data, function(item){
        return _.split(item.name,' ',1)[0];
    }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use JavaScript [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) methods.

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "John Smith"
}, {
  "name": "Mary Kay"
}, {
  "name": "Peter Pan"
}, {
  "name": "Ben Franklin"
}];

console.log(
  // iterate over the array to generate result array
  data.map(function(v) {
    // split the value by space and return first element
    return v.name.split(' ')[0];
  })
)

// with  ES6 arrow function 
console.log(
  data.map(v => v.name.split(' ')[0])
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative that makes use of lodash' [flow()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flow), that executes [property()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#property) to get the property of each item in an object (e.g. `name`), [words()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#words), to split strings into words (array), and lastly, [first()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#first) to get the first item from an array.

```
var result = _.map(source, _.flow(_.property('name'), _.words, _.first));
```

```js
var source = [{
  "name": "John Smith"
}, {
  "name": "Mary Kay"
}, {
  "name": "Peter Pan"
}, {
  "name": "Ben Franklin"
}];

var result = _.map(source, _.flow(_.property('name'), _.words, _.first));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Here's another implementation of the solution above that does not use `flow()` and `property()`:

```
var result = _.map(source, function(item) {
  return _(item.name).words().first();
});
```

```js
var source = [{
  "name": "John Smith"
}, {
  "name": "Mary Kay"
}, {
  "name": "Peter Pan"
}, {
  "name": "Ben Franklin"
}];

var result = _.map(source, function(item) {
  return _(item.name).words().first();
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var t = [
        {
            "name":"John Smith"
        },
        {
            "name":"Mary Kay"
        },
        {
            "name":"Peter Pan"
        },
        {
            "name":"Ben Franklin"
        }
    ];
    var result = [];
    t.forEach(function(element) {
       result.push(element.name)
    });
    console.log(result)
```

Comment: Oh yeah, only first names. My bad

Answer (score 0):

If you like short code (using parameter destructuring to extract name):

```
result = _.map(data, ({name}) => _.words(name)[0]);
```